# Freely positionable element (by user) on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, fluid

Is this possible?  I don't have an example of what I'm asking about obviously, but essentially what I want to do is to have users be able to drag an element around a page, but not have it be restrained to certain positions like drag and drop-able elements in HTML5.  The simplest example would be the way windows work on the desktop.  I'm sorry if the answer is out there, but I don't know the term to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for jQueryUI!

Enable draggable functionality on any DOM element. Move the draggable object by clicking on it with the mouse and dragging it anywhere within the viewport.

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/